# Using C# to set System.Drawing.Color.FromName

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, rowdatabound, system.drawing.color

Objective: The objective is to set the System.Drawing.Color dynamically based on a text value within a datatable. The text value is the name of a color within System.Drawing.Color. The purpose is to change the backcolor of a grid based on the given value.

Issue: The method I am using now does not obtain a value from the datatable and sets the Color to 0,0,0,0. The datatable is created using a ViewState. The research I've conducted on this issue indicates this should work. However, the value obtained from the DataTable is "" . What is incorrect in this code? Thank you in advance for you comments, suggestions and consideration. The code is as follows:

DataTable code

```
private void CreateList()
{
    DataTable dtMyList = new DataTable();

    DataColumn dcID = new DataColumn("ID");
    dtMyList.Columns.Add(dcID);

    DataColumn dcColor = new DataColumn("Color");
    dtMyList.Columns.Add(dcColor);

    ViewState["MyList"] =  dtMyList;

 }
```

On RowDataBound code intended to change the backcolor

```
protected void grdMyList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEventsArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtMyList = (DataTable)ViewState["MyList"];

    for (int i = 0; i < dtMyList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(dtMyList.Rows[0]["Color"]));

    }
}
```

Comment: You're referencing three different `DataTable` variables in your event handler - 'MyList', `dtMyList`, and `dtCommentList`.  Are they in sync?

Comment: that was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Is the datatable filled with any data?

Second: you are trying to fill that one row (given in the event args) with all the colors from the datatable, resulting in that only one property (`e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor`) is filled with the color coming from the last row in the table (`dtMyList.Rows[i]["Color"]`).

I think you should first lookup the correct datarow which is attached to your gridrow (`e.Row.DataItem`), then read its color and then fill the property of your gridrow. Like this:

```
protected void grdMyList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEventsArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = (DataRow)e.Row.DataItem;
    e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(row["Color"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: The datatable is filled with data. That makes sense let me try that and see if it works.

Comment: I changed the index to 0. However, the value e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor is still Name=0, ARGB=(0,0,0,0)

Comment: What happens if you add a breakpoint at that line. What is the value inside row["Color"], what is the result of `System.Drawing.Color.FromName(row["Color"].ToString())`, and what is the result in BackColor after that line is executed?

Comment: At that line the value is being set to 0, i.e. an unknown color. This leads to me to think that I am pulling the data incorrectly from the datatable

Comment: At this moment I cannot help you with that since I cannot see the relation between your gridview and your datable. I mean: I cannot see how they are bound.

Comment: I am going to look into this, but do you see anything wrong with the code currently apart from the correction you made earlier?

Comment: Did you modify it? I was sure your line said: `dtMyList.Rows[i]["Color"]`. Is your iteration variable `i`  used anywehre?

Comment: Well... in that case my recommendation would be: Remove the for-line. Or use my code example :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through the entire table and setting the color *for each row*.  I think you want something like

```
protected void grdMyList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEventsArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtMyList = (DataTable)ViewState["MyList"];

    index i = e.Row.RowIndex;
    e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(dtMyList.Rows[i]["Color"]));

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I am trying to set the color for each row.

Comment: Right - and the event handler fires for each row, but you are looping through the entire table.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you mean. Thank you.